# Ubuntu does not detects the RAM correctly

Tags: ram

I have 512MB RAM in my PC. Ubuntu detects only 495 MiB. How can I fix this?

On Debian Squeeze, I have 512MB.(The correct size)

OS: Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin

Comment: How are you measuring it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your RAM is detected correctly. MB (megabyte) and MiB (mebibyte) are two different units.

- 1 MB is 1000 KB which is 1000 byte (decimal)
- 1 MiB is 1024 KiB which is 1024 byte (binary)

If you check the math yourself you will see that 512 MB are 495 MiB ;-)

MB is mostly used for selling stuff because it's the higher number. In your Ubuntu system you will mostly encounter MiB (or GiB).

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mebibyte

Comment: If this were the case, then 512 MB of ram would be 488 MiB, not 495.  Ram modules come in powers of two, so 512 MB is 512 * 1024 * 1024 bytes, not 512 million bytes.  It is just hard drive vendors that lie and use powers of 10 to make their drives look larger.

Comment: @psusi Alright that's strange. I didn't do the math myself as I am used to that offset and never really think of it anymore. I have also seen it with RAM many times, not only hard drives.

Comment: @stonedsquirrel, nope.. ram modules always comes in even powers of two.  Any less reported than you physically have is overhead of some kind, such as the kernel or bios reserved memory.

Comment: @psusi Good to know. My bad! Sorry for that!

Comment: Aren't these written the wrong way round? 1MB is 1000000 (10**6) bytes and 1MiB is 1048576 (2**20) bytes.

Comment: @chronitis Oh s**** you are right. Shame on myself. Will edit my answer...

Comment: Wait, that wasn't my mistake. The edit of @AmithKK was wrong. And I already started to doubt myself.

Comment: Sorry, I got confused with the base notation

Answer (score -1):

a) At startup, the BIOS counts the number of working RAM-bytes, but EXCLUDES the ram-bank used for the test. That difference is fully normal. -- b)  Any faulty RAM-bank is neither used nor counted. In that case, the computer can still be used for non-important jobs.

Comment: This is true but wrong, and doesn't apply here